# How to Rotate a rectangular object, controlled by a knob using action script?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am stuck with the rotation I have set the movieclip's registration point to be the center in which i am loading the uploaded image. I am doing something like

http://custom.case-mate.com/diy?bypassLandingPage=true

I have uploaded the image but unable to rotate it properly and zoom also isnt working from the center.. Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A good start would be to post the code you have tried so we can correct it for you.

Comment: Thank you I am going to post the code and the required files 

https://rapidshare.com/files/931307868/flashApp.zip please have a look at it and let me know what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd suggest creating a `Sprite`, adding the loaded image as its child (i suppose you're using a `Loader`) and centering it relatively to its parent:

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void{
    _parentSprite.addChild(_loader);
    _loader.x = -_loader.width / 2;
    _loader.y = -_loader.height / 2;
}
```

after that you'll get the desired rotation type changing  `_parentSprite.rotation` .

every time you're zooming, you'll have to call something like:

```
function centerContent():void{
    _loader.x = -(_loader.width * _loader.scaleX) / 2;
    _loader.y = -(_loader.height * _loader.scaleY) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i will definitely try this

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly fine with the code now the rotation and zoom in out are being done just the way i wanted. 

There's one last thing, can you please guide me how to resize the image as it gets loaded so that it fits the container it has to be in.

Like for now when i upload the picture it is too large and i want to scale it according to the container.. is that feasible?

Comment: @user1456593: if you need to preserve proportions of the loaded image, you'll have to calculate `kx = container.width / loader.width` and `ky = container.height / loader.height` and then set `loader.scaleX = loader.scaleY = ky > kx ? kx : ky`